# React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'fetchComments'. Either include it or remove the dependency array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Why it is lacking dependancy issue

```
const [ comments, setComment ] = useState([])

    const fetchComments = async () => {
        const res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:4001/posts/${postid}/comments`);
        setComment(res.data);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchComments();
    }, [postid]);

    console.log("IsArray", Array.isArray(comments)); // Returns me true, true, true then warning after warning it become false, false
```

Why it behave like this I did same approach for post list it does work fine but fetching with specific ID it sends me error. Please guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's eslint error. Because the `useEffect` use `fetchComments` in its callback function there some way to solve it.

- wrap `fetchComments` by useCallback and then include `fetchComments` in dependencies array

```js
 const fetchComments = useCallback(async () => {
        const res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:4001/posts/${postid}/comments`);
        setComment(res.data);
    },[postid])

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchComments();
    }, [fetchComments]);
```

- defined the function in useEffect

```js
 useEffect(() => {
    const fetchComments = async () => {
      const res = await axios.get(
        `http://localhost:4001/posts/${postid}/comments`
      );
      setComment(res.data);
    };
    fetchComments();
 }, [postid]);
```

- disable eslint error (not recommended)

```js
const fetchComments = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get(
      `http://localhost:4001/posts/${postid}/comments`
    );
    setComment(res.data);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    fetchComments();
}, [postid]);
```

Comment: Still if I tried const 

renderComments = comments.map(comment => {
            return (
                   <li key={comment.id}>{comment.content}</li> 
            )
        })
console.log(renderComments)
it does say comments.map is not a function
but I do console.log(comments it does display data)

Comment: @SunilDubey What is the type of `data`? Could you include it in your question? Make sure it's an array.

Comment: Yes it is 
66b2077b: Array(13)
0: {id: "aa1aba56", content: "teaser"}
1: {id: "d8efbcd1", content: "test"}

Comment: @SunilDubey There is only one place you call `setComment(res.data);` if the `res.data` is an array, you won't get that issue and ` console.log("IsArray", Array.isArray(comments));` must be true. With that information you posted, there is no way `comments` becomes non-array type if `res.data` is an array.

Comment: Ohh I got it thanks for your support, I was returning object instead array

Comment: I am glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

"postid" is not a direct dependency of the useEffect hook. So either move your fetchComments function inside useEffect hook (as below)

```
useEffect(() => {
   const fetchComments = async () => {
     const res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:4001/posts/${postid}/comments`);
     setComment(res.data);
   }
   fetchComments();
}, [postid]);
```

OR add fetchComments function as dependency

```
useEffect(() => {
   fetchComments();
}, [fetchComments]);
```

Comment: In second option, if you don't wrap `fetchComments` with useCallback you might get recursively re-render. Check my comment for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The argument provided to useEffect, means that the function in useEffect will run whenever the argument changes. So, useEffect has dependency on that argument.

Here you are providing **postid** as a dependency of useEffect but not using it in useEffect. That's why react suggests that **postid** has no use here, either include the **fetchComment** as a dependecy or remove **postid** from there .

Since, you want to run **fetchcomments** whenever **postid** is changed,
You can simply re-write it like this.

```
const [ comments, setComment ] = useState([])

const fetchComments = async (postid) => {
    const res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:4001/posts/${postid}/comments`);
    setComment(res.data);
}

useEffect(() => {
    fetchComments(postid);
}, [postid]);
```